# ¿Cuando usa Git Bash en java se hace commit a estos dos archivos ".metadata/" y "RemoteSystemsTempFile"?

Tags: java

No quiero usar la interfaz gráfica que ofrece eclipse para GIT...mi duda es, al usar Git Bash si se tendría que hacer commit a estos dos archivos (.metadata/ RemoteSystemsTempFiles)??? estoy usando java se [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una buena practica es mantener fuera del repositorio todos archivos que no tengan  nada que ver en la ejecucion del codigo(como los archivos .eclise o .idea). Si deseas mas ayuda necesitaria conocer la estructura de tu proyecto.

Comment: Gracias amigo por la respuesta...he usado git con visual code y no tuve problemas, arrancaba git-bash desde la carpeta del proyecto principal, y hacia commit a los 3 archivos (html-css-js) ___Hice los mismo con java se, arranqué git-bash desde la carpeta principal del proyecto, el tema es que eclipse te crea 3 archivos: 1.- el nombre del proyecto que creastes  2_.metadata  y 3_ RemoteSystemsTempFile_ mi duda es, se tiene que hacer comit a los 3 archivos?? hasta ahora no he tenido problemas haciendo commit solo a al archivo 1 que lleva el nombre del proyecto, pero no sé si estoy haciendo bien

Comment: No, solo a al 1 los demas se autogeneran con el ide